# How can I create an instance from a own class in FreeMarker (FTL)

Tags: java, freemarker

I wish to instantiate a java class that I have defined in my domain and I want to use it from my FTL code in this way, but I'm getting an error.

```
<#assign myClassInstance = "com.domain.MyClass"?new())>
```

Is it possible? What I should change to do it?

`MyClass` doesn't implements the `TemplateModel`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function for instantiating arbitrary non-`TemplateModel` classes... maybe there should be a setting to allow that for `?new`. Anyway, for now you can write a `TemplateMethodModelEx` that does that, and then you can pull that into some of your commonly included/imported templates like `<#assign unrestrictedNew = "com.example.UnrestrictedNewMethodModel"?new()>` (or just put the instance into the data-model or into the `Configuration` as a shared variable) and then you can do `<#assign myClassInstance = unrestrictedNew("com.domain.MyClass")(arg1, arg2, argN)>` in your templates. There are two tricky parts in implementing such a `TemplateMethodModel`. One is resolving the class name to a `Class`, for which I recommend `env.getNewBuiltinClassResolver().resolve(className, env, null)`, where `env` is the current `freemarker.core.Environment` object. The other is calling the constructor, as then you have to convert parameter values and possibly chose an overloaded constructor. For that I recommend calling `ow = env.getObjectWrapper()`, see if `ow instanceof BeansWrapper` (throw exception if it isn't), then do `return ((BeansWrapper) ow).newInstance(cl, arguments)`.